# why does height work on inline-flex containers

Tags: html, css

Setting height on inline elements doesn't work.

Setting height on inline-flex elements work even though it shouldn't!

why does setting height on an inline-element work in the below example?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


div {

    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
span {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container{
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <span class="container">
            <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

EDIT:

The linked question does not explain why `inline-flex` accepts a height.

`inline` elements do not accept a height!
setting an element to `inline-flex` set's the element outer display mode to `inline`,

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? `inline` is not the same thing as `inline-block` or `inline-flex`. Nothing says you can't set a height on the latter two.

Comment: inline elements shouldn't accept a height. and setting the element as `inline-flex` should set the element's outer display to `inline` while only setting the inner display to `flex`

Comment: You’re free to believe that they shouldn’t, but they do, and I’ve never seen anything that says otherwise and I’ve been doing this stuff for a long time.

Answer (score -2):

There is no css code as name `display:inline-element`. You can use here `display:inline-block` and `display:inline-flex` its make div flexible for get the items inline.